# How <dd> evil keymap works?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

`d` seems to be bound to `evil-delete` which requires `beg` and `end` arguments. I suspect they are somehow obtained from `d` motion. Let's say I have `defun my-delete-line (body)`. What should go in `body` to emulate `<dd>`?

Comment: Do you want to emulate `<dd>`? Or do you want to `kill-whole-line`?

Comment: @Zeta I want to emulate `<dd>`.

Comment: The question how `dd` works has been answered on https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/mezr4b/how_is_dd_evil_keymap_implemented_internally/ already. "Emulate dd" isn't nearly clear enough. Hence my vote to close as it's two different questions and expecting people to answer both with little clarification is unreasonable.